# Hover effects in for loops

Tags: javascript

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class=column1of4>
    <a rel="Appendix" href="images/watermarks/watermark_pic1.jpg" 
       title="Bottle in the  mirror">
        <img src="images/250-width/pic1.jpg" 
             alt="" width="250px" height="250px"
             id="Bottleinthemirrorpic">
    </a>
    <a rel="Appendix" href="images/watermarks/watermark_pic1.jpg" 
       title="Bottle in the mirror">
        <div id="Bottleinthemirror" class="spanlink">
            <p>Bottle in the mirror</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and here is the Javascript:

```
var texts = ['#Bottleinthemirror'];
var picture = ['#Bottleinthemirrorpic'];

for ( var i = 0; i < 1; ++i ) {

$.each(texts, function(i) {
    $(this).hide();
    $([this, picture[i]]).hover(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Basically, when I hover over `#Bottleinthemirrorpic`, I want `#Bottleinthemirror` to show up and I want `#Bottleinthemirror` to go away when I hover off of both of them.

I want the for loop because I am going to add more elements to texts and picture, I'm just wondering why the Javascript doesn't work? It doesn't seem to hide `#Bottleinthemirror`.

This code works but I want to be able to loop through the elements inside texts and picture which is why I am not using this code:

```
$('#Bottleinthemirror').hide();
$('#Bottleinthemirrorpic, #Bottleinthemirror').hover(function() {
  // in
  $('#Bottleinthemirror').show();
}, function() {
  // out
  $('#Bottleinthemirror').hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm confused why you have a `for` loop, as well as an `$.each` loop

Comment: I assume you have actually loaded jQuery

Comment: @Ian The for loop is because, say I add one more element to both texts and picture, then I can just change the for loop to for ( var i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {, this way, the code will repeat for i=1 and i=2.

Comment: @MikeW I have loaded Jquery-1.7.1 yes, I have it installed and I am linking to the file. Plus, since the last bit of code I provided works (the non looped code), it means I have JQuery loaded right? Or is there a different JQuery I require for the looped code?

Comment: @user216485 I still don't see the need for **both**. You only need to have one loop. If it helps, here's how I'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/hQ8xt/

Comment: @user216485 If something works you have jQuery loaded. Why use such an old version? jQuery is now on v1.9.x

Comment: @Ian, perfect, thanks! That works great! Also, suppose I remove the for ( var i = 0; i < 1; ++i ) {, would my code work? Does it look right or is there something incorrect about it?

Comment: @MikeW jQuery's now on 1.10.2 and 2.0.3

Comment: @MikeW oh because I was working with a friends existing old code and when he first created the site, it was linking to 1.7.1 so I just stuck with it. But right, I should use a newer version now, thanks for that. I didn't notice I was working with such an old version.

Comment: @user216485 Don't just blindly upgrade to the newest version. There are **many** changes since 1.7, including deprecated and removed features. So try it out, read the docs, and make sure everything works. If it helps, there's a jQuery Migrate plugin that restores removed features and warns you in the console

Comment: Looking through the earlier comments, it appears to now be solved, but syntax-wise either your JS above is incomplete or you're missing the closing `}` on the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested loops are unnecessary, where the arrays are one-dimensional. You can try something like:

```
var texts = ['#Bottleinthemirror'],
    pictures = ['#Bottleinthemirrorpic'],
    i, j, curText, curPicture, generateHandlers;

generateHandlers = function (text, picture) {
    $(text).hide();
    $(text + "," + picture).hover(function () {
        //in
        $(text).show();
    },function () {
        //out
        $(text).hide();
    });
};

for (i = 0, j = texts.length; i < j; i++) {
    curText = texts[i];
    curPicture = pictures[i];
    generateHandlers(curText, curPicture);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hQ8xt/

The immediate problem with binding events in a loop is that the event is triggered **later**, when the loop has finished. So by that time, the iterator (in this case, `i`) has reached the last value (in this case, `j`). You need to create a new scope to capture the values in the arrays, which is what I've done by calling the `generatedHandlers` function and passing the array values.

One thing I'd suggest is to combine the `texts` and `pictures` arrays into an object, like:

```
var textPics = {
    '#Bottleinthemirror': '#Bottleinthemirrorpic'
};
```

And loop over that like:

```
var curText, curPicture;
for (curText in textPics) {
    curPicture = textPics[curText];
    generateHandlers(curText, curPicture);
}
```